# How do I register a new user in eJabberd server through C# Client?

Tags: c#, ejabberd

I'm developing a messenger type application with Jabbernet Server & library. Currently I'm having a problem registering new users.

First of all I want to know, is it required to login as admin to register a new user?

I tried to register with and without admin login but it always "`Not Authorized`".

```
JID jid = new JID("test4", server_IP_address, "");
JClient.User = "test4";
JClient.Password = "test4";
JClient.AutoLogin = false;

JClient.OnLoginRequired += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(this.OnLoginRequired);
JClient.OnRegisterInfo += new RegisterInfoHandler(this.OnRegisterInfo);
JClient.OnRegistered += new IQHandler(this.OnRegistered);

JClient.Connect();
JClient.Register(jid);
JClient.Close(true);

return true;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the host name, which is required by the register method
try using help to get full explanation in the parameters you must pass with register method, at least as far as I understand your question.